# ordonate pagination codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i have a problem with my url. My pagination works very well, but it dont look so nice. 
For example i wanna to see page 2 and the link become: `localhost/page/9` and page 3 become `localhost/page/18`
i try this function:

```
if($this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']))
    {
        $offset = $this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']);
        $segment_to_replace = $this->uri->segment(2);
        $new_id = $this->uri->segment(2) / 9 +1;
        $new_url = str_replace ($segment_to_replace, $new_id, current_url());
        redirect($new_url);
    }
```

But the code is not working. 
First, `var_dup($new_url)` return localhost/page/2 and `redirect($new_url)` return localhost/page/1.222222222.
Another problem is continous redirect. How can i make the URL to show curent page and not the offset of my code.

COMPLETE CODE:

```
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/page/';

    $config['total_rows'] = $this->product_model->count('active');
    $config['per_page'] = 9;
    $config['num_links'] = 3;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = ' <b>';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    if($this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']))
    {
        $offset = $this->uri->segment($config['uri_segment']);
        $segment_to_replace = $this->uri->segment(2);
        $new_id = $this->uri->segment(2) / 9 +1;
        $new_url = str_replace ($segment_to_replace, $new_id, current_url());

        var_dump($new_url); die;
        return redirect($new_url);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```

> By default, the URI segment will use the starting index for the items
>   you are paginating. If you prefer to show the the actual page number,
>   set this to TRUE.

[Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html#customizing-the-pagination).

Comment: Cheers. Happy coding. :)